# Extracting a json value from bash shell using awk without having to resort to both awk and sed

Tags: awk, sed, aws, json

The aws command returns a json string to stdout inside a bash shell.

```
$ aws ssm get-parameter --name /mysite/dev/email
{
    "Parameter": {
        "Name": "/mysite/dev/email",
        "Type": "String",
        "Value": "admin@example.com",
        "Version": 1
    }
}
```

I want to return the value of "Value" without the quotes wrapping it. I used a combination of awk and sed linux programs. Basically, awk searches each line in the input and allows you to return a line that has a matching value. Since awk scans a file line by line, allowing you to split the line into fields and perform action on matched pattern, I did this first:

```
$ aws ssm get-parameter --name /mysite/dev/email | awk -F: '/Value/ {print $2}'

"admin@example.com",
```

As you can see, I used : as a delimited via the F flag. I matched the line with the string "Value" and then printed the second part of the delimited string, which is the value "user@example.com",

But the quotes and comma are unwelcomed. So I had to use sed with the -E regex flag to replace the quotes and comma:

```
$ aws ssm get-parameter --name /mysite/dev/email | awk -F: '/Value/ {print $2}' | sed -E 's/"|",//g'
 admin@example.com
```

I got the desired result, but I would prefer to just use awk, instead of having to pipe awk to sed. Is it possible?

Comment: The jq program is designed to manipulate json data.

Comment: ok, that's good to know. I just have to run this in an aws lifecycle hook, which executes a shell script, and to avoid any possible issues during the deploy, I planned to stay away from installing packages e.g. apt-get install jq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a one-liner, you can just remove **all** commas and quotes first.

```
awk '/Value/ { gsub(/[",]/,""); print $2}'
```

A better translation of your awk | sed pipeline would be

```
awk '/Value/ { gsub(/[",]/,"",$2); print $2}'
```

to just alter the values in the second field.

Comment: Note that if the value of e.g. `Name` contains the string `Value`, this may return unexpected data.

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed. Using something like `jq` to parse the data rather than pattern match is clearly the better solution (like using `sh` rather than `csh`). The answer given is to the question as asked. I pointed out in the comments that `jq` would be a suitable tool, and the OP clarified that he didn't want to install any extra packages.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jq` to parse out the value of the `Value` key in the top-level `Parameter` structure:

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name /mysite/dev/email | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'
```

This will additionally decode any JSON encoding of the value, so that a value that is stored in JSON as `\"The Admin\" <admin@example.com>` comes back as `"The Admin" <admin@example.com>`.